# ruby splitting array for watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, arrays, watir-webdriver

is there a way to split an array in half and then access each half 1 at a time like 
array[0] then array[1] then do something with each half?

I am populating the array for a select list and want to run through the list half at a time, due to website timing out.

When selecting all of the accounts at once, either manually or through ruby watir-webdriver script website times out.

This is how I was doing it.

```
b.select_list(:id => 'ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ContentPlaceHolder2_ListBoxAllAcct').options.each { |option| option.select }
b.button(:id => 'ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ContentPlaceHolder2_LinkButtonAddAcct').click
```

Then I tried one at a time but takes to long and creates to many file downloads, on for each option value.

```
elems = Array.new
values = Array.new
elems = b.select_list(:id => "ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ContentPlaceHolder2_ListBoxAllAcct").options
0.upto(elems.length - 1) do |i|
  values.push elems[i].text
end

0.upto(values.length - 1) do |i|
  puts values[i]
  b.select_list(:id =>   'ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ContentPlaceHolder2_ListBoxAllAcct').select values[i]
  b.button(:id => 'ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ContentPlaceHolder2_LinkButtonAddAcct').click
end
```

I am simply trying to find a way to select and process the first half the list then move one to the second set of the list.  Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `half = list[0,list.size/2]` would give you the first half of list, is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi Stefan,  Yes I am looking to grab half the list, select, then hit button and run through next steps.  Repeat for second half of the list.  Thanks for reply

Comment: I have no idea about the watir part of the problem, but the second half of the list would be `list[list.size/2..-1]`. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
values = b.select_list(id: 
  'ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ContentPlaceHolder2_ListBoxAllAcct').options.map(&:text)

bulk_size = values.length / 2

values.each_slice(bulk_size) do |bulk_values|
  b.select_list(id: 
  'ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ContentPlaceHolder2_ListBoxAllAcct').options.select do |option|
    bulk_values.include? option.text
  end.each do |option|
    option.select
  end
  b.button(id:
    'ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ContentPlaceHolder2_LinkButtonAddAcct').click
end
```

If you see that half is still too much of a bulk, you can simply play with `bulk_size`, setting it to `10` for example, instead of `values.length / 2`